# How to Consolidate Color Swatches in Layered Navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, color-swatches

hoping someone can help me with a question on Magento 1.9.1.

I set-up multiple configurable products where some products do not share a common global color such as "Blue".

Example, there are colors that are Blue but are named differently:

-Blue
-Ocean Blue
-Marine Blue
-Sky Blue

For each color, I created swatch image files - blue.png, ocean-blue.png, marine-blue.png, sky-blue.png.

Everything works well but when I enable the "COLOR" attribute to display in Layered Sidebar Navigation it displays the color swatches for all the variations of "Blue" ?

Is there any way I can group all these very similar instances under the main color "BLUE" so that when a visitor in a category clicks on the swatch it will list all products that are related to this color?

I can't seem to find a way to do it.

If anybody has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

-Pavel

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible by default, one solution that you could use is adding an extra attribute where you define the main colors (blue, red and more) and use that attribute only in your layered navigation. The current color swatch attribute is then only used for the product selection and has the real color varian (ie ocean blue).

Comment: I concur with this solution. Seems to be the only out-of-box solution that I could come up with myself after playing around with settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieve same thing I created two Attribute One for regular colorsuch as `Marine blue` and all and other contains `blue` and `red`.

So user create a simple product at that time user select two attribute `marine Blue` and in other attribute `blue`

and I have added one color in layered navigation that contains `red` & `blue` colors this way.

So this way I solve this problem